# bootstrap 4 dropdown with search not working in react

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

i tried to use this form in a `react` component's `render()` function, but `live search` option is not working, please help me to solve this issue,

```
<form className="container" id="input-validate" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} noValidate>
  <div className="col-xs-5 selectContainer">
    <select required data-live-search="true" name="patient_id" className="form-control" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange}>
      <option value="">select patient</option>
      {patient_data_all.map((item) =>
        <option key={item._id} value={item._id}>{item.patient_name}</option>
      )}
    </select>
    <span id='message'></span>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" className="btn btn-info btn-block mt-4" />
</form>
```

onChange:

```
onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
```

Comment: Side note: There isn't any `col-xs` in Bootstrap 4. It's just `col`.

Comment: @Klooven ok sure, do you have any idea about why search is not working in dropdown

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select
   required
   data-live-search="true"
   name="patient_id" 
   className="form-control"
   value={this.state.value}
   onChange={this.onChange}
 >
   <option value="">select patient</option>
    {patient_data_all.map((item) =>
        <option key={item._id} value={item._id}>{item.patient_name}</option>
    )}
 </select>




onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
```

Here you are setting the value of select box with `this.state.value` and setting the new value to the `e.target.name` i.e `patient_id` so if you change  `this.state.value` then it will reflect the current value.
modify your `onChange` handler.

```
onChange(e) {
        this.setState({value: e.target.value })
    }
```

Comment: functionality wise my coding is working, but dropdown box not showing that search option, i want solution for that issue